# Generating function with one parameter in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

How can I develop a model in simulink which on code generation generates a function of the following nature which takes one parameter as an argument:

```
void DoProcessing(ReceiveEvent enEvent)
{
    switch(enEvent)
    {
      case a:
             abcd();
             break;
      case b:
             efgh();
             break;
     }
 }
```

So , How to model a function talking one parameter in simulink?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are compiling the Simulink model or just want a block in simulink to behave as you described, so here there are both solutions:

There is a block in simulink called "[Embebed Matlab code](http://www.mathworks.es/products/matlab-coder/description5.html)" where you can write whatever function you want in Matlab language. It can have any inputs and outputs you want.

If what you are doing is compiling the simulink model to ".c" files, and you want a block to do that, why not just directly write it in C?

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the reply. 
I have to generate C code out of the model. But I prefer doing it graphically without writing the actual code. Well the main aim is to make everything graphical and then generate the code so that the user will not have to write the code manually.

Is there a way to implement that function completely graphically using the blocks available in the 'Simulink Library Browser'?

Comment: @GuiccoPiano There is a block Matlab 2012b and laters that allows the user to write matlab code in simulink, the one called "Embebed Matlab code". Try to find it. You can write a typical function as in matlab and It will convert it to a block that executes that function.

Comment: @GuiccoPiano Sorry I meant Matlab 2010b

Comment: @GuiccoPiano Sorry, I don't have any idea how to do that :(. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is close enough (1,2 instead of a and b):

[image]

Comment: Thanks but may be I should reframe the question correctly:
Refer to original question: ReceiveEvent is an object of an enum, already defined in my system outside matlab. Thus I do not want to define this enum again in matlab. So in short I want to import enum from somewhere outside matlab.
Referring to the above code format, enEvent is a varaible of the type of ReceiveEvent.
Now my problem is how to design a model in matlab or what setting needs to be done to obtain a function which takes a parameter of enum type(that too the enum is defined external to matlab) on code generation.